# Deriving Show for Algebraic Data Type

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following types:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade deriving Show
data Rank = R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving Show
data JokerColor = Red | Black deriving Show
data JCard = NormalCard Suit Rank | JokerCard JokerColor
```

How can I show JCard? Currently I get `No instance for (Show JCard)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just derive show for `JCard` in the same way you did for `JokerColor`.

```
data JokerColor = Red | Black deriving Show
data JCard = NormalCard Suit Rank | JokerCard JokerColor deriving Show
```

For most types, people typically derive Eq, Ord, and Show.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting unrelated errors before and thought this syntax was incorrect...